# How to Debug Jenkins Pipeline node hangs on allocating node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Any suggestions on debugging a pipeline hang?

When Jenkins 2.7.2 with pipeline plugins 2.2 cannot execute any pipeline job attempting to allocate a node.

**Test**

1. 20+ nodes free
2. 3 free executors on master
3. Start pipeline job
4. got gets to *allocating node* and hangs
5. start DoNothing freestyle job that does nothing but run on a node
6. DoNothing freestyle waits in queue even though 20+ nodes report as free
7. Kill pipeline job
8. DoNothing freestyle job finds a node, executes, completes

**Clues - alas, not many**

There's nothing in jenkins master log and in my preprod with the same plugins, everything works.

I suspect I have something getting in the way but i'm not sure what and really don't want to restart (but I think I need to)

**Logs**

```
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
Waiting for next available executor
```

**Pipeline Script**

```
echo 'Starting'
sleep time: 1, unit: 'NANOSECONDS'
echo 'Slept 1 NS'

node {
    echo "On a node"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you actually have available executors on that Jenkins?

Comment: Thanks. I do have many executors free. I can start a tiny pipeline  job then start a tiny non pipeline job and both hold until I kill the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting jenkins cleared the problem.  I suspect, when we attempted to clear a hung build by killing a thread, we selected the wrong thread creating the problem or it was just a fluke.